# How to sum columns in matrices according to a certain rule?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

now I have a lot of matrices with the different number of rows. And I want to sum the odd-number rows and even number rows element respectivelylike below:

```
o <- matrix(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),6),ncol = 6)
o2 <- matrix(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),12),ncol = 6)   
#I want to sum the odd-number rows and even number rows element respectively
i=1
kg <- NULL
while(i <= 2){
op<-unlist(Map(sum,o[i,],o[i+2,],o[i+4,]))
kg <- c(kg,op)
i=i+1
}

i=1
kg2 <- NULL
while(i <= 2){
op2<-unlist(Map(sum,o2[i,],o2[i+2,],o2[i+4,],o2[i+6],o2[i+8],o2[i+10]))
kg2 <- c(kg2,op2)
i=i+1
}
kg
kg2 #the result should be a vector sequence like kg and kg2
> kg2
[1] 18 18 18 18 18 18 24 24 24 24 24 24
```

It is what I can do know. But my data have a lot of different length of columns. Is that any method I can do it quickly?

And how can I generate a sring like "o2[i,],o2[i+2,],o2[i+4,],o2[i+6],o2[i+8],o2[i+10])"  automatically according to the input number? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @akrun thank you for your answer. But I want to sum the odd-row and even row elements respectively. And get a result like this > kg2
[1] 18 18 18 18 18 18 24 24 24 24 24 24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the OP's loop, if we want to change the `Map` to make it more automatic

```
unlist(do.call(Map, c(f = sum, as.data.frame(t(o2[seq(i, i+10, by = 2),])))))
```

---

Using the full code

```
o <- matrix(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),6),ncol = 6)
o2 <- matrix(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),12),ncol = 6)   
#I want to sum the odd-number rows and even number rows
i=1
kg <- NULL
while(i <= 2){
#op<-unlist(Map(sum,o[i,],o[i+2,],o[i+4,]))
op <- unlist(do.call(Map, c(f = sum, 
        as.data.frame(t(o[seq(i, i+4, by = 2),]))))) # change here

kg <- c(kg,op)
i=i+1
}

i=1
kg2 <- NULL
while(i <= 2){
#op2<-unlist(Map(sum,o2[i,],o2[i+2,],o2[i+4,],o2[i+6],o2[i+8],o2[i+10]))
op2 <- unlist(do.call(Map, c(f = sum, 
               s.data.frame(t(o2[seq(i, i+10, by = 2),]))))) # change here

kg2 <- c(kg2,op2)
i=i+1
}
kg
#[1]  9  9  9  9  9  9 12 12 12 12 12 12

kg2
#[1] 18 18 18 18 18 18 24 24 24 24 24 24
```

---

In the OP's code, if we analyze the individual arguments of `Map` with just two arguments i.e. the first and 3rd row of 'o'

```
i <- 1
Map(function(x, y) c(x, y),  o[i,], o[i+2,])
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 1 3

#[[3]]
#[1] 1 3

#[[4]]
#[1] 1 3

#[[5]]
#[1] 1 3

#[[6]]
#[1] 1 3
```

Here, each element of the `list` is the column values concatenated (`c`).  If we need to get a similar structure, by subsetting the odd rows, we transpose the subset of rows, convert it to data.frame, so that each individual block is a column (that corresponds to the original rows subsetted)

```
do.call(Map, c(f=c, as.data.frame(t(o[c(i, i+2),]))))
#[[1]]
#V1 V2 
# 1  3 

#[[2]]
#V1 V2 
# 1  3 

#[[3]]
#V1 V2 
# 1  3 

#[[4]]
#V1 V2 
# 1  3 

#[[5]]
#V1 V2 
# 1  3 

#[[6]]
#V1 V2 
# 1  3
```

Keeping it as a `matrix` will not solve it as it take the whole matrix as a single cell (a `matrix` is a `vector` with dimension attribute)

```
do.call(Map, c(f=c, o[c(i, i+2),]))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3
```

while using `Map` directly will loop through each element of the `matrix` (`vector`) instead of each column

```
Map(c, o[c(i, i+2),]) # check the output
```

Another option would be to `split` the object by `col` and then do the `sum`

```
onew <- o[seq(i, i+4, by = 2),]
Map(sum, split(onew, col(onew)))
```

---

The above approach is loopy, but we can also use vectorized approach (just like in the @Maurits Evers post).  Instead of `seq`, here we are using the recycling of logical vector to subset the rows and then do the `colSums`

```
i1 <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
colSums(cbind(o[i1,], o[!i1,]))
#[1]  9  9  9  9  9  9 12 12 12 12 12 12

colSums(cbind(o2[i1,], o2[!i1,]))
#[1] 18 18 18 18 18 18 24 24 24 24 24 24
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun your answer works perfectly. But I don't understand the meaning of code : op2 <- unlist(do.call(Map, c(f = sum,           s.data.frame(t(o2[seq(i, i+10, by = 2),]))))) Could you explain it to me thank you.

Comment: @Codezy Updated with some explanations.  Hope it works

Comment: Thank you so much it did help

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps something like this?

```
o <- matrix(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),6),ncol = 6)
o2 <- matrix(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),12),ncol = 6)

even <- function(x) 2 * seq(1, nrow(x) / 2);
odd <- function(x) 2 * seq(1, nrow(x) / 2) - 1;

colSums(o[even(o), ]);
#[1] 12 12 12 12 12 12

colSums(o[odd(o), ]);
#[1] 9 9 9 9 9 9

colSums(o2[even(o2), ]);
#[1] 24 24 24 24 24 24

colSums(o2[odd(o2), ]);
#[1] 18 18 18 18 18 18
```

Explanation: `even`/`odd` return even/odd row indices of a `matrix`/`data.frame`; we can then use `colSums` to sum entries by column.

---

### Update

To sum entries from rows `3, 6, 9, 12` (or any other sequence) you just need to define a corresponding function, e.g.

```
another_seq <- function(x) 3 * seq(1, nrow(x) / 3)
colSums(o2[another_seq(o2), ]);
#[1] 18 18 18 18 18 18
```

Comment: wow, your answer works, thank you. One more question: what if I want to sum the rows of (1,4,7,10) (2,5,8,11)and (3,6,9,12), how can I do that? your answer can only work for even and odd numbers.

Comment: You're very welcome @Codezy; you can just define different functions that return indices for the rows that you want to sum. I've updated my solution to give an example for summing entries in rows `3, 6, 9, 12`. Please take a look.